# Convert POJO to data class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pojo, data-class

Recently I started converting my Android project from Java to Kotlin. I am using Retrofit in many classes for fetching data from API. In my project, there are many POJO's and I need to convert them manually to data classes as it doesn't work well with the auto converter tool of Android Studio.

Consider I have model class:

```
public class LoginResponseMinimal {

String firstName, lastName, token;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
 }
}
```

Is there any good way that I can directly convert this model class to data class in Kotlin? It's okay for this class to convert manually but I have some classes which have a large number of variables and it would be cumbersome to manually convert it to the data class.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with auto converter tool of Android Studio?

Comment: It just converts it to the normal class in Kotlin and not the data class @chandil03

Comment: so u want getter and setter method also...android studio is no showing u getter and setter methods after code convert to kotlin...right?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya to remind you, there is not such thing like data class in Java. So when you try to convert a POJO class it will convert to its equivalent in Kotlin. So you have to manually convert your POJOs to data class in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to help you. Here is the `solution` :

https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt

visit this `link` , then go on option given on upper corner **convert from java**

then paste your `java` code there and on bottom side you will see button **convert to kotlin** , hit that button and you will get your `kotlin` code on right side.

**And yes do not paste your whole class**

In your case , paste this below code :

```
String firstName, lastName, token;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
 }
```